# How do I send email while running tests in django?

Tags: python, django, email, testing

I am trying to send an email while running tests in django.

When I run a test that sends email everything runs without error, but the actual email is not sent.

I am confident the code in `test_send_mail` works because I've called it with manage.py runserver and the email shows up in the inboxes of `recipient_list`. This makes me suspect django is doing something to prevent the email from sending during testing. Is my suspicion correct? How can I disable this feature if it exists? Alternatively, where am I going wrong with the test code?

test_email.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class TestEmail(TestCase):
    def test_send_mail(self):
        subject = 'test email'
        message = 'Sent by test_email.py.'
        from_email = '...'
        recipient_list = [...]
        n_sent = send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
        self.assertEqual(n_sent, 1)
```

Comment: The point of unit testing is that it is isolated from any external dependencies. Email is about as external as it gets. As John points out, you should use the built-in testing tools to check email functionality.

Answer (score 4):

During unittesting django.core.mail overrides all EMAIL settings with `backends.locmem.EmailBackend`

There are provisions for handling emails during testing.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#email-services